# How to create Fact table in Hive and replace original values in table with key (id) values

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hue

What I want to create I explanied below. Is that possible to do in Hive?

I could do that in Python using Pandas and replace over columns, but I was wondering can that be done with query in Hive?

I have uploaded Source table in Hive and created Dimensional tables like below also (in Cloudera HUE), so is it possible to somehow create that Fact table by using Dimensional tables **id** values and replace values in Source table?

**I have my Source table:**

[image: SOURCE TABLE]

**I create Dimensional tables from Source table:**

[image] [image] [image]

**And I want to create Fact table like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join by values with source table and select IDs:

```
insert overwrite table fact
select pr.id as property, t.id as type, pl.id as place, s.price
 from source_table s 
      left join property_dim pr on s.property=pr.property
      left join type_dim     t  on s.type=t.type
      left join place_dim    pl on s.place=pl.place
```

Comment: i had to change query a bit but everything was worked properly, thanks!
p.s. sorry for late response